# Purpose of name in Typescript index signature?

Tags: typescript

I can do this in Typescript:

```js
type Foo = {[key: string]: number}
```

However, what is the purpose of "key"? Why not just say

```js
type Foo = {[string]: number}
```

Comment: I presume to prevent some weird Javascript shennanigans since you can dynamically set properties when the name is a variable and you write `const foo: ComplexObject = { [variableThatHasPropertyNameToWriteTo]: 1 };`. Forgot the name of this interpolation. That is my assumption, but nothing to back it up though.

Comment: Oh and to add to this, the name doesn't matter in the end and is a nice way of documenting the type itself.